# Is ROSARIA going to be made available in Groovy?

Tags: ros, rosaria, ros-groovy, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA

The instructions located on the wiki page appear to be for ROS-F, and the ROSARIA packages do not appear to be available for ROS-G.

Also, the p2os driver is missing from ROS-G. (Understandable since it hasn't been maintained for well over a year.)

Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53725/is-rosaria-going-to-be-made-available-in-groovy?/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-01-30**:
Keeping track of progress, I think I found the repo ROSARIA is from: https://code.google.com/p/amor-ros-pkg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated the wiki page with a solution. Use rosws to grab the packages directly from the upstream repo and build per the existing instructions on the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4